# Foundation's grid system: Hiding an element when screen becomes smaller doesn't work

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I've got a three-columns layout. The idea is that the most right column shall vanish on small screens.

```css
.rect {
  background-color: lime;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="large-4 column rect">FIRST</div>
  <div class="large-4 column rect">SECOND</div>
  <div class="large-4 column rect show-for-medium-up">THIRD</div>
</div>
```

I think I've used correct class-names. Rest of coding should be alright too.

But it doesn't and I've no good idea why.

**Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class=" large-4 column rect hide-for-small-only ">THIRD</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong class, use `hide-for-small-only` or `show-for-medium`:

```css
.rect {
  background-color: lime;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.0/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="large-4 column rect">FIRST</div>
  <div class="large-4 column rect">SECOND</div>
  <div class="large-4 column rect hide-for-small-only">THIRD</div>
</div>
```

Read more [Zurb Foundation Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/visibility.html)